# R - logical vector has same value across the vector

Tags: r

i have a logical vector i

```
> i
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

j <- i*1
j
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do i know if j has 0 only in the vector?

Comment: Compare the `sum` and the `length` of `j`.

Comment: You know you can do what the guys said above in your logical vector straight away. No need to transform logical values to numeric first. Like : all(i==FALSE), or sum(i)

Comment: or `all(i)` since you seem to wanna try this on `i` ...